# Normally ON Switch using N-CH MOSFET and pull-up resistor

Tags: transistors, mosfet, switching, pullup

I am learning about electronics and am having a hard time finding a normally closed (i.e. on) switch using transistors and FETs. Am I violating any rules with the circuit below which is using an enhancement mode N-channel MOSFET with an NPN driver transistor? Can I simply pull up the FET's gate high with R1 to keep the switch on (by default)?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAtovF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: This  circuit is fine. You have the right of it.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, that's perfectly valid (should be a base resistor on the BJT, of course).

Another method you might use could be to use a P-channel MOSFET with a pull-down resistor (just the complement of your circuit). However this does **not** work if the power is removed from the micro since the protection circuit will drag down the output pin. Your circuit also allows the micro to switch a higher voltage than its supply (for example a 3.3V  output switching a 5V or 12V circuit).

Edit: Added are two additional circuits- one using another NPN transistor which will work with power removed from the micro and using an opto as you suggested. Both are high-side switches and the opto one adds isolation while actually simplifying the circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIMP7K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A third approach is to use a depletion mode MOSFET or a JFET but that's a lot trickier because you have to come up with a negative voltage to turn the transistor off. It does work in the absence of any significant voltage supply though. Another disadvantage is that power devices are unavailable in P-channel type.

Comment: Well, for a lot of low-current applications, PMOS is available. But when very low Rds is needed, you have to go to NMOS. For up to 500mA or maybe 2A, PMOS can probably be used if it is easier.

Comment: @mkeith I've never seen anything *depletion mode* that is P-channel other than JFET and RF parts. If you have a source (pun intended) please share.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies! Regarding Sephro's circuit with the high-side PMOS, I need to keep the load on when uC loses power  Could this be overcome by adding a optoisolator e.g. Vishay VOS618A between uC output and Q1?

Comment: I can add drawing if my comment is unclear. But overall, I prefer the PMOS high circuit because R_load is always connected to ground.  Btw, mKeith I found a PMOS with 20mOhm RDSON and rated to 11 A drain current: ON Semiconductor P/N NTMS4177P

Comment: @Bolek Sure, see my edit above. You can replace Q1 with the opto and cut out the middleman.

Comment: Available enhancement mode PMOS transistors actually seem to be better than similarly priced NMOS for low voltages- flying against physics considerations of carrier mobility. Perhaps because they've been optimized as load switches.

Comment: Thank you very much Spehro and mKeith!  Are there any gratitude points I can give you on this forum???

Comment: I misread. It was not clear to me that the "power devices are not available" applied only to depletion mode, although on second reading it probably should have been clear.

Comment: @mkeith Drat, Oh, well, it would have been nice. There are depletion mode opto SSRs which work in either direction but they are very sluggish.

Comment: @Bolek, for gratitude, just upvote Spehro's answer if you haven't already, and if you find it satisfactory, accept it. I accept your comment as gratitude. ;-)

Comment: What mkeith said. It's best to wait a day or so before accepting an answer- to do otherwise discourages potential better answers.

Comment: In my experience, answers that are better than the accepted answer garner a lot more upvotes over time than they would get if they were accepted in the first place. Add to that the fact that the asker can change the accepted answer at any time, and I don't see why anyone would be discouraged.